# EWS The Autodiscover service couldn't be located

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using C# EWS (ExchangeWebServices).
I have ExchangeServer i.e with the following IP: 10.81.5.1.
Now, I'm trying to access to ExchangeServer like the follow:

```
 ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);

 service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myuser", "mypassword", "10.81.5.1");
 service.TraceEnabled = true;
 service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
 service.AutodiscoverUrl("myuser@mydomain.local", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);//Throw an exception
```

And I got the following exception:

> The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

How i know my ExchangeServer domain?

When I'm changed the following **(and run the code inside the ExchangeServer machine)**

```
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
```

Meaning the domain is the localhost i'm success to run my code without exception.

What is the mistake at my code?

What i need to write instead "10.81.5.1" if I'm not running the code inside the ExchangeServer machine? How can i know my ExchangeServer "domain"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason of my problem was that the exchange server and my develop machine isn't on the same domain.
Solved  by removed the follow line:

```
 service.AutodiscoverUrl("myuser@mydomain.local", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);//Throw an exception
```

And add the uri of the .asmx EWS :

```
service.Url = new Uri("https://IP/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

Comment: Exchange.asmx URL is subjected to change AutodiscoverUrl helps to get latest URL. So we should not hard code exchange web service URL.

Comment: We should not hard-code the EWS endpoint in code, since you never know user is on-premise or on Office 365 (cloud) and Autodiscovery service helps to set the service.Url automatically. Also. check for proxy settings. In my case, the proxy settings disallowed the Autodiscovery service. I never knew it until I saw network trace where it showed 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

The following 3 lines worked for me:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("<loginID..not email address>", "< the pw>");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("<your emailaddress>",RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

If your login id is abc123. that's good enough. i need specify the domain

Comment: Is it good practice to use passwords in plain text for production environment?

Answer (score 0):

On my machine (win7), I can find it here: Control Panel - System - Computer name, domain and workgroup settings. Maybe you can have a try.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your solution but it's still not working for me